# Is Super User aimed at Microsoft users?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

A couple of days ago, I've asked [a question](https://superuser.com/questions/254428/seriously-is-there-a-microsoft-english-dictionary) and it was closed so quick I couldn't even react.

As the question was somewhat pointed and concerned working with Windows I was asking myself if I may have offended some Windows user's beliefs.  Is Super User a place for Microsoft users?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To answer your title question: No, Super User is open to any format, technology, company product, or anything computer related.

As to that question:  Your original tone of the original post really gave off a rant feel. That is not accepted by users well and is discouraged on Super User.  You are looking for help by asking a question, so it is a good thing to make people feel like they want to answer your question.  We also want quality questions and answers on Super User.

As to the close reason:  I have to agree with the close reason to a degree, because what you are asking for is pretty much a tech dictionary specific to Microsoft.  I do not think something like that even exists. The best thing I can think of is their support forums and the related parts of their website and looking up a particular term or idea your looking for.

Comment: However, having reviewed the question that is under the microscope here, I think perhaps that the "people in charge" exercised a bit more authority than was warranted. Microsoft DOES tend to abuse terminology that already has a well accepted meaning. And the question he asked was valid... Is there a reference somewhere that explains MS usage (or abuseage) versus the normally accepted usage?

Comment: And what is the problem with a "rant"? I mean the decision by someone to close a question they don't like (or a question by someone they don't like) could be just as much a "rant". I mean "Who's watching the watchers?"

Comment: I agree with @Troggy.

Comment: @Zeke  The "people in charge" that closed that question were just a collection of 5 users.  No moderator action was performed on that question.  That was an example of community moderation.

Answer (score 8):

The problem was not with the topic of your question, but with the phrasing.  It's quite possible to ask that question in a way that isn't insulting or excessively snarky, and around here clarity and at least *some* objectivity are highly valued.  (Heck, ask it right and it might well end up being a community reference.)

Comment: If there was not a problem with the question, then politely asking the person to rephrase the question would be in order. Just closing the question without directly contacting the questioner seems to be an abuse of power.

Comment: "Objectivity is in the eye of the beholder."

Comment: @Zeke:  Let's put it this way:  if you walk into a Windows user group meeting and ask your question that way, what do you think would happen?  Just because it's online and nobody can deck you in person doesn't mean it's okay to use inflammatory rhetoric.  And I can't hep but think you're engaging in sophistry to justify anti-social behavior in the above comments; communities do have standards, and you shouldn't expect them to adapt to your preferences just because they're online.

Comment: There is no abuse of power. you're free to edit it and flag for moderator attention asking for a reopen @ZekeHansell

Comment: But, ONLY the original poster can do that. Others who have answered and commented, and found the question useful have no such venue.

Comment: @geek, I like your use of the big word "sophistry" to make my comment sound trivial and irrelevant. I guess the civil rights movement was wrong for engaging in "anti-social" behavior.